# Cannot implicitly convert type float to float[]

Tags: c#, error-handling

Getting error `Error    CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'float' to 'float[]'` when trying to compile this code

```
        float[] timeValues;

        float time;

        while (lineBeingRead != null)
        {
            valueSplit = lineBeingRead.Split(exerciseDivider);
            for (int i = 0; i < valueSplit.Length; i++)
            {
                if (valueSplit[i].Contains(textToFind))
                {
                    exerciseLine = valueSplit[i];

                    string[] timeValuesString = exerciseLine.Split(timeDivider);

                    for (int a = 0; a < timeValuesString.Length; i++)
                    {
                        time = float.Parse(timeValuesString[1]);
                        timeValues = time;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Does anyone have any idea what is going on here? I can't figure this out and I couldn't find any answers out there.

Comment: It means that the left hand of one of your assignments is defined as a float array but you are trying to put a float value in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to assign a float number to an array (not adding it as an element of array). So you must first initialize your array with a predefined size: `timeValues = new float[neededLength]`. But if you don't know the size you need, the `List<float>` type is better choice as below code:

```
//float[] timeValues;
List<float> timeValues = new List<float>();

float time;

while (lineBeingRead != null)
{
    valueSplit = lineBeingRead.Split(exerciseDivider);
    for (int i = 0; i < valueSplit.Length; i++)
    {
        if (valueSplit[i].Contains(textToFind))
        {
            exerciseLine = valueSplit[i];

            string[] timeValuesString = exerciseLine.Split(timeDivider);

            for (int a = 0; a < timeValuesString.Length; i++)
            {
                time = float.Parse(timeValuesString[1]);
                //timeValues = time;
                timeValues.add(time);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also you can convert your list to array when needed just by calling it's `ToArray` method:

```
var timeArray = timeValues.ToArray();
```

Comment: Did you test your code? This line `List<float> timeValues = new List<float> timeValues;` will not work. Wrong object creation!

Comment: I edited my code and changed first line to `List<float> timeValues = new List<float>();`. Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

You need to instantiate your array before using it and you can not assign single flot to whole array. Change following part of your code

```
string[] timeValuesString = exerciseLine.Split(timeDivider);

timeValues = new float[timeValuesString.Length]; // CHANGE-1

for (int a = 0; a < timeValuesString.Length; i++)
{
    time = float.Parse(timeValuesString[1]);
    timeValues[a] = time; // CHANGE-2
}
```